# GDPR legitimate interest and Contact Picker API

Tags: united-kingdom, gdpr

There is a draft web standard Contact Picker API see [here](https://web.dev/contact-picker/) and [here](https://wicg.github.io/contact-api/spec/).  An explicit use case is "bootstrapping a user’s social graph for social networks".  I'm interested in what ways this can and can't be used when using legitimate interest as the basis for processing under GDPR.

It's for a charity - which probably doesn't affect the law, but might affect your desire to help :-).

For example, could one:

- Ask a user to select contacts to invite to a service
- Pass that information (email and/or phone number) to servers
- Send an invitation from the servers to the contact (by email or SMS)
- Not retain the information further

[This](https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/email-marketing) suggests that it might be permissible because of

- Legitimate interest as the legal basis.
- The "relevant and proportionate relationship" being that someone who already knows you has suggested that you might be interested in a service.

This is in the UK, so I'm interested in any other legislation that applies there.

Comment: This is quite broad - are you asking for the set of possible ways to use a contact picker legally under GDPR?  That seems almost infinite.

Comment: A couple of examples of how it would be legal would be very useful.

Comment: The API is not necessarily relevant: if you ask your users to *type* their personal data, you'd have the same requirement for processing as if they filled the form using the API.

Comment: One thing I've looked at is using the contact information purely on the client, to construct links which will send the invitation via the user's own existing services (SMS, WhatsApp, email).  It feels (but feelings are not law) as though that's significantly different from sending data off the device to the servers.